# It takes too long time to mux h264 into mp4 file using mp4parser

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec, mp4parser

I'm using mp4parser to mux h264 file and aac file into mp4 file.And the code is as belows.

```
    String h264Path = "path to my h264 file, generated by Android MediaCodec";

    DataSource videoFile = new FileDataSourceImpl(h264Path);

    H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(videoFile, "eng", 5, 1); // 5fps. you can play with timescale and timetick to get non integer fps, 23.967 is 24000/1001

    Movie movie = new Movie();

    movie.addTrack(h264Track);

    Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("path to my generated file.mp4"));
    out.writeContainer(fos.getChannel());

    fos.close();
```

But when I debug it,it takes about 4 mins on this step:

```
    DataSource videoFile = new FileDataSourceImpl(h264Path);
```

And my sample h264 video file is about 20 seconds in duration and 3MB in size(about 178KB in bitrate).It's generated by MediaCodec.That's really not acceptable in production environment. Is there some mistake in my code?Or is it the real efficiency of mp4parser?Very Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give the right path of `H264` file, then it will debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google's [ExoPlayer library](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) though I believe MP4 extraction is only available on the dev branch, see [demo code here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/dev/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo).